# Cordova can't build ios

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have Cordova version (8.0.0)

Am trying to build the ios but shows a msg without any error and stops the build.

```
> Building for iPhone X Simulator Building project: /Users/FaisalAlzahrani/Customer_Prod_3/platforms/ios/Ajeer-Client.xcworkspace   Configuration: Debug    Platform: emulator Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/FaisalAlzahrani/Customer_Prod_3/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.1
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/FaisalAlzahrani/Customer_Prod_3/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch Build settings from configuration file '/Users/FaisalAlzahrani/Customer_Prod_3/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h
```

[image]

Comment: can you post some more information?

Comment: This is all the information i have :( i tried to build the project many times but no error msg shows so i can't look into the problem

Answer (score 2):

i fixed the problem by using the below command in building the project

```
cordova build ios --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

Comment: In my case, the build doesn't stop but freeze at the step described above. I tried this, and it solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode 10, the new build setting can be activated from Xcode Files-> Project/Workspace Settings where options to toggle between Legacy system and new build system. 
    To build manually for iOS platform we must use build flag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
Reference : https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407

```
cordova build ios --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
This will works !
Below error I was facing used the same solution
4001009: Invalid .ipa file: missing embedded mobileprovisionvalid .ipa file: missing embedded mobileprovision facing same problem.

Package.json file can also be included the below flag
"buildFlag": [
  "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
]
```